# Insert into numpy array with condition from another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array `arr` containing 0s and 1s,

```
arr = np.random.randint(2, size=(800,800))
```

Then I casted it to `astype(np.float32)` and inserted various float numbers at various positions. In fact, what I would like to do is insert those float numbers only where the original array had `1` rather than `0`; where the original array had `0` I want to keep `0`.

My thought was to take a copy of the array (with `.copy()`) and reinsert from that later. So now I have `arr` above (1s and 0s), and a same-shaped array `arr2` with numerical elements. I want to replace the elements in `arr2` with those in `arr` only where (and everywhere where) the element in `arr` is 0. How can I do this?

Small example:

```
arr = np.array([1,0],
               [0,1])
arr2 = np.array([2.43, 5.25],
                [1.54, 2.59])
```

Desired output:

```
arr2 = np.array([2.43, 0],
                [0, 2.59])
```

N.B. should be as fast as possible on arrays of around 800x800

Comment: Please provide the code that you have worked on.

Comment: ```arr2 * arr``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
arr2[arr == 0] = 0
```

or

```
arr2 = arr2 * arr
```

Comment: Fastest method wins (arr2 = arr2*arr)

Comment: Even faster: `arr2 *= arr`

Comment: Nice! Forgot that inplace operations can be used here to further optimize this.

Answer (score 1):

@swag2198 is correct, an alternative is below

Numpy has a functin called 'where' which allows you to set values based on a condition from another array - this is essentially masking

below will achieve what you want - essentially it will return an array the same dimensions as arr2, except wherever there is a zero in arr, it will be replaced with zero

```
arr = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
arr2 = np.array([[2.43, 5.25],
                [1.54, 2.59]])


arr_out = np.where(arr, arr2, 0)
```

the advantage of this way is that you can pick values based on two arrays if you wish - say you wanted to mask an image for instance - replace the background